# What is the name of the popular buffer algorithm?

Tags: buffer, algorithm

There is a well-known algorithm that I believe is used for the "buffer" function in some GIS libraries and applications. I have a vivid memory of reading the paper that describes the algorithm and illustrates how it works, but now I am quite embarrassed: I seem to have misplaced the PDF, and I can't remember the *name* of the algorithm either. The paper was very interesting and I was hoping to read it again.

Can anyone help with a suggestion of what the algorithm is called that I may be (poorly) remembering? I checked the source code for a couple of libraries but didn't see a reference to the algorithm name.

Of course there is probably more than one such algorithm, but I will recognize the one I was thinking of when I see the name and look at the paper again.

Comment: Could it be this paper? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1295244

Comment: Check this reference as well [An algorithm for generating geometric buffers for vector feature layers](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10095020.2012.747643).